# How to call JavaScript method when click on the p:calender next and previous icon?

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I am developing a project with Primefaces.

In my project, I need to call the JavaScript method when click on the `p:calendar` previous button (icon)?

I have tried with some scenario but no use.

### Sample Code:

```
$('.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header .ui-datepicker-prev').click(function() {
    invoke();
});

function invoke() {
   alert('Invoked');
}
```

The `.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header .ui-datepicker-prev` are the `p:calendar` default classes.

Comment: Please add the calendar's HTML structure to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [jQuery's event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) mechanism as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/4026/

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-header .ui-datepicker-prev', function() 
{
     alert("Prev clicked");
});
```